# How to enable fcitx input method in an fltk program running on linux?

Tags: fltk, fcitx

I'm trying to input some Chinese characters in my fltk program running on linux but failed. I'm using fcitx, and specifically `fcitx-googlepinyin` as the Chinese input method.

The following code will produce a single window containing a single input box.

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Input.H>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Fl::scheme("GTK+");

    Fl::background(35, 35, 35);
    Fl::background2(90, 90, 90);
    Fl::foreground(240, 240, 240);

    Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(640, 480);

    Fl_Input *input = new Fl_Input(20, 20, 200, 20);

    window->end();
    window->show(argc, argv);

    return Fl::run();
}
```

When I click on the input box, I can't switch to my Chinese input method by pressing `ctrl + space` in the fltk program. But in other GUI programs like Firefox or Atom the Chinese input method works well.

I've set some variables as follows:

```
export XIM="fcitx"
export XIM_PROGRAM="fcitx"
export XMODIFIERS="@im=fcitx"
export GTK_IM_MODULE="fcitx"
export QT_IM_MODULE="fcitx"
```

How to enable fcitx input method in an fltk program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying X input method, I discover that this is a bug in fltk >= 1.3.4 (fltk-1.3.3 has the correct implementation).

On line 673 of `src/Fl_x.cxx`, the correct code should be `XSetLocaleModifiers("");` instead of `XSetLocaleModifiers("@im=");`. Line 1329 has the same problem.

Just correct these two lines of code and recompile the library, the input methods will work correctly again.

I've also posted a [bug report](http://www.fltk.org/str.php?L3502+P0+S-2+C0+I0+E0+V1.3%25+Q) on the website of fltk, check it for more detail.